# Find $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2-4b$ and $b^2-4a$ are perfect squares

Tags: number-theory

Under what conditions for $a$ and $b$ are $(1)$ and $(2)$ integers?
$$\sqrt{a^2-4b}\tag{1}$$
$$\sqrt{b^2-4a}\tag{2}$$
Apologies, but my only attempt is to show that $a^2-4b$ and $b^2-4a$ are perfect squares, but even on that I have no idea how to approach.

Comment: Did you by any chance come from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686575/find-integer-roots-for-quadratic)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But I can see why you would say that. :)

Comment: An answer to this question would solve the one in the link :)

Comment: Yes I see that :)  [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41337/efficient-way-to-determine-if-a-number-is-perfect-square) tells me to use modular arithmetic, binary search or the integer version of newton's method, but I have no idea to use them.

Comment: I have found one condition $ab\ge 16$ but i don't think it would be complete.

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik The statement "$mn$ is a square if and only if $m$ and $n$ are squares" is not true. You need the condition that $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Right, my bad. For instance 100=20*5. I'll remove my misleading comment

Comment: The use of modular arithmetic is very compelling, but i havent any idea how to use it. Haha

Comment: @JohnGlenn  Are $a$ and $b$ positive integers ?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Numerically it seems as if $(4,4)$, $(5,6), and $(6,5)$ are the only solutions.

Comment: Is that by trial and error? Or could there possibly exist infinitely many combinations for A and B?

Comment: please refine question based on answers you have given in comments.

Answer (score 1):

We claim the only solutions are $(4,4)$, $(5,6)$, and $(6,5)$.

Without loss of generality, let $a\leq b$. Then either $b\leq 4$ or

$$(b-3)^2 <b^2-4b \leq b^2-4a \leq b^2.$$

(we have that $(b-3)^2<b^2-4b$ if $b>9/2$.) The case where $b\leq 4$ can be hand-bashed out to reveal only the solution $\boxed{(4,4)}$. Otherwise, as $b^2-4a$ is a square between $(b-3)^2$ and $b^2$, it is either $(b-2)^2$ or $(b-1)^2$. However, we have

$$b^2-4a=(b-1)^2=b^2-2b+1 \implies 4a=2b-1,$$

which is a contradiction since $2b-1$ is odd and thus not a multiple of $4$. So, $b^2-4a=(b-2)^2$, which gives $a=b-1$. Then, we have that

$$a^2-4b=(b-1)^2-4b=b^2-6b+1$$

is a square. However, if $b\geq 15/2$, we have that

$$(b-4)^2=b^2-8b+16 < b^2-6b+1 < b^2-6b+9 = (b-3)^2,$$

a contradiction. Thus, $b\leq 15/2$, reducing the problem to a finite case check revealing only $\boxed{(5,6)}$, and correspondingly $\boxed{(6,5)}$.

Comment: Have you considered negative values? e.g. $a=2$ and $b=-3$

Comment: sorry missed comment above that $a$ and $b$ positive.

Comment: @JamesArathoon I haven't (per the comment), but after some testing it seems as if the only solutions are those with $a+b=-1$ and $a=-n^2,b=0$ or vice versa.

Comment: @JamesArathoon Just an addendum; it's actually not that hard to prove that the solutions mentioned in my previous comment are the only ones where one of $\{a,b\}$ is allowed to be non-positive: just split into cases and use the fact that there are no positive integers $a,b$ such that $a^2+4b$ is a square and $b\leq a$.